# Upgrading to a development snapshot

Tags: updating

I currently use Drupal 7.0.

I am thinking that upgrading to 7.x-dev would resolve some performance issues I have.
Do you think that upgrading a production site to the development snapshot would break any possible database upgrade path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to use the 7.x-1.x-dev version now. The updates happen incrementally, based on a number that is updated for every new update function.

It was only before the 7.x-1.x-beta releases, where upgrading was not supported (And apart from some bugs during the beta IIRC) for the -dev version.

Comment: So upgrading from one 7.x-1.x-dev to another date's 7.x-1.x-dev is supported?

Comment: Yes. At a given point in time, the 7.x branch is being tagged as 7.number and released. Apart from a few minor changes like hardcoded version number constants, there is nothing special about a stable version, technically.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, using a development snapshot could create problems while updating from two releases of the same development snapshot; this is because there could not be an update path from the previous release to the latest release of a development snapshot.

Talking of Drupal, I remember that when I was testing Drupal 7 on my computer, and I used the development snapshot, I had to install the latest release from scratch all times. I don't remember if that happened before Drupal 7 had an official release, or it was still true when Drupal 7 had an official release.

Considering that Angie Byron (a.k.a. webchick, the maintainer of Drupal 7) reported a [schedule for the release of the next Drupal 7 official releases](http://groups.drupal.org/node/150854), I would wait for the next official release, which (basing on that schedule) should happen today.

Comment: thanks for indicating the schedule URL. I hope it will get release soon.